# Drawing a simple line on a JPEG image

Tags: swift, image, macos, quartz

I'm stuck again with an apparently simple question.

I loaded a JPEG file into a CGImage. I got the correct values for width and height (in pixels) and was able to show "myImage" in a ImageView Controller. But I wanted to add some graphics on this image and found that I should instead get it into a NSImage. So I did but got different (proportional) values for width and height: 595.08 instead for 1653, and 841.68 instead of 2338, respectively.

I tried to create a NSCGContext from a CGContext 'gc' for drawing (a simple line and a rectangle) which resulted in a "Value of optional type 'CGContext?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"... I'm lost...

```
// with NSData
//
let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: chosenFiles[0])
let imageProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageAsData as CFData)
var myImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: imageProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
let imageWidth = myImage!.width
let imageHeight = myImage!.height

// with NSImage, now
//
let imageAsNSImage=NSImage(contentsOf: chosenFiles[0])
let imageSize=imageAsNSImage?.size      // ---> 0.36 * pixels 

// creating a CG context and drawing
//
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let gc = CGContext(data: nil, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0,space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)
let NSGContext = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: gc, flipped: true)
let currentContext = NSGraphicsContext.current()  // Cocoa GC object appropriate for the current drawing environment
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGContext
NSGContext?.beginPath()
NSGContext?.setStrokeColor(redColor)
NSGContext?.setLineWidth(50.0)
NSGContext?.move(to: targetStart)
NSGContext?.addLine(to: targetEnd)
NSGContext?.setStrokeColor(grayColor)
NSGContext?.setFillColor(grayColor)
NSGContext?.addRect(ROIRect)
NSGContext?.closePath()
NSGContext.restoreGraphicsState()
imageAsNSImage?.draw(at: NSZeroPoint, from: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
imageAsNSImage?.unlockFocus()
NSGraphicsContext.setcurrent(currentContext)
myImageView.image = imageAsNSImage  // image & drawings should show in View
```

Comment: Nobody knows under what class you are writing your code.  You create a CGImage object for what purpose?

Comment: I created a CGImage to later access to the pixels (not shown here). I need to detect a line within a ROI (Region of Interest) using a Probabilistic Hough Transform, which already works more or less... Anyway, the NSImage is to show the image under treatment in an ImageView on which I want to draw the target line (in yellow) and the ROI (in gray). The images are scanned and have to be redressed/rescaled/translated for the detected line to fit the target line. This is done to improve the results of the Optimal Mark Recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Drawing a simple line on a JPEG image

```
// load JPEG from main bundle
guard let path = Bundle.main.pathForImageResource(NSImage.Name("picture.jpg")),
      let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: path)
else { fatalError() }
let size = image.size

image.lockFocus()  // prepare image for drawing

NSColor.red.setStroke()
NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: .zero, to: NSPoint(x: size.width, y: size.height))

image.unlockFocus()  // drawing commands done
```

The code above strokes a red line from lower left corner to top right.
If you have an `NSImageView` at hand you can use the image directly:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: NSImageView!
...
imageView.image = image
```

Comment: Thank you, djromero. This helps a lot and the elegance of the solution is so frustrating to me. However, the origin (0,0) is - as expected - at the lower left corner of the image and the size is not in pixels - as I mentioned in my original post. Any thought?

Comment: Doing so, I get a NSImage with the same size of the CGImage and I'm able to draw lines and show the NSImage, and also work at pixel-level for Hough Transform... but the origin of the NSImage is still at the lower-left corner!


let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: chosenFiles[0])
let imageProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageAsData as CFData)
var myImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: imageProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
let imageAsNSImage=NSImage(cgImage: myImage!, size: NSZeroSize)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to djromero, here is the solution I just reached:

```
// Load the JPEG image from disk into a CGImage
//
let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: chosenFiles[0])
let imageProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageAsData as CFData)
var myImage = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: imageProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

// Create a NSImage from the CGImage (with the same width and height in pixels)
//
let imageAsNSImage=NSImage(cgImage: myImage!, size: NSZeroSize)

// Drawing a simple line
//
imageAsNSImage.lockFocusFlipped(true) // Otherwise, the origin is at the lower left corner
NSColor.red.setStroke()
NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: targetStart, to: targetEnd)
imageAsNSImage.unlockFocus()

// Show the NSImage in the NSImageView
//
myImageView.image = imageAsNSImage
```